# Alter table merge 2 rows with same value in column

Tags: php, mysql, alter

I have a table and I would like to merge the data of two rows having the same name, like this:

```
id | name    | price | priced

1  | Samsung | 100   | 0

2  | Samsung | 0     | 500
```

---

I'd like the final input to be:

```
id               | name    | price | priced

(doesn't matter) | Samsung | 100   | 500
```

Comment: Can you define what exactly you mean by *merge* ?

Comment: Do you want to add the two columns ? Also do you want to replace the current table or just make a select query ?

Comment: replace the current table

Comment: I am trying to understand more. Do you want to merge the rows with the same name?

Comment: yes, exactly, I want to merge the rows with the same name

Comment: How do you propose dealing with cases where both `price` and `priced` are non-zero? When the are both zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id, name,MAX(price) as price, MAX(priced) as priced
FROM TableName
GROUP BY name
```

To insert into a table:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES
(SELECT MAX(id) as id, name,MAX(price) as price, MAX(priced) as priced
FROM TableName
GROUP BY name)
```

**EDIT**

As you say, to merge (insert new and delete others)

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES
(SELECT MAX(id)+1 as id, name,MAX(price) as price, MAX(priced) as priced
FROM TableName
GROUP BY name)

--Now deleting others
DELETE T1 FROM TableName T1, TableName T2 WHERE T1.id < T2.id AND T1.name = T2.name
```

Comment: I need to merge the columns in the table, not fetch them

Comment: You'll need to fetch them and then insert them somewhere (either the same table or a different one). @RagingBull is solving the important part of the problem for you.

Comment: Isn't there a way to alter the table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757082/mysql-fetch-array-table-results how to fetch

Comment: @NirTzezana: Edited my answer. See the edit. I think thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you wanna this?

```
 select id , name,
 sum(price) as price, sum(priced) as priced from table1
 group by name
```

Comment: You would need max or min ID for this to make sense. I know MySQL will let you do this group by but it is illogical and prone to giving the wrong results. **NOTE TO ALL MYSQL DEVS** Stop doing `GROUP BY` this way!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to add the prices not get the maximum. I think you should make a new table 'table2' and add rows to it the following way :

```
INSERT INTO table2 Values (
SELECT
  name,
  SUM(price),
  SUM(priced)
FROM table1
GROUP BY name )
```

Then delete table1. This way you will add the rows with the same name from table1