# How do I make a MySQL infinite array table?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, infinite-loop, infinite

I am using this code to create an infinite table for my mysql queries:

```
<table cellspacing='0'> <!-- cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->

    <!-- Table Header -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>SteamID</th>
            <th>Banned by</th>
            <th>Admin SteamID</th>
            <th>Time Banned (min)</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Table Header -->

    <!-- Table Body -->
    <tbody>
<?php

echo '<tr>';

for($i = 0; $bans = mysqli_fetch_array($query2); $i = ($i+1)%3){
    echo '<td>'.$bans['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$bans['steamid'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$bans['nameAdmin'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$bans['steamidAdmin'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$bans['time'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$bans['reason'].'</td>';
    if($i == 2)
        echo '</tr><tr>';
}

echo '</tr>';

?>

</tbody>
```

I got that code from [Mysql fetch array, table results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757082/mysql-fetch-array-table-results)

It works fine, except it doesn't CORRECTLY go further down than 6 rows. The other rows for whatever reason are placed to the right of my last column as shown in this screenshot:
http://puu.sh/h0qZF/a12de1dd87.png

How can I fix this? Is there something wrong with my code? Why is it happening?

Comment: `while (true) echo "<tr>never ending</tr>";`

Comment: What do you mean by an "infinite table"?, when you say that, an infinite loop triggers in my mind, and why would you want that?

Comment: I just mean that the table's rows will be the same amount of rows that are in the databasetable that I am selecting from. it's the concept found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757082/mysql-fetch-array-table-results

Comment: @adeneo It's not an infinite loop :)

Comment: One of your users got kicked off for being homosexual!?

Comment: @IMSoP No, that was a test ban. I am not homophobic.

Comment: @Aris Glad to hear it :)

Comment: Why do you have this `$i = ($i+1)%3` for your increment counter? Are you trying to skip some iterations?? If so, explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your looping makes no sense. Using `$i` to inject new rows, like is done here, is not necessary; you can just loop over each row and then output it as a row:

```
<table>
    <!-- <thead>...</thead> -->
    <tbody>
<?php while ($bans = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $bans['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $bans['steamid'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $bans['nameAdmin'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $bans['steamidAdmin'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $bans['time'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $bans['reason'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endwhile ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly after pasting in! (despite the fact that you put $band instead of $bans)

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop as instructed [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) . So something like this:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($bans = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<td>'.$bans['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$bans['steamid'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$bans['nameAdmin'].'</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making two columns.

You have code that will print out the end of the table row every two sets of data:

```
if($i == 2)
    echo '</tr><tr>';
```

It should just be `echo '</tr><tr>';`